# How can I use sort command to sort the log file only by the first field in Linux?

Tags: linux, sorting

I have a log file named `a.log` !  I want sort it by the fisrt field ! If two lines have the same field , the order will be original contens‘！
contents:

```
 1. 101  c
 2. 100  b
 3. 100  a
 4. 2    d
```

I expect the result:

```
 1. 2    d
 2. 100  b
 3. 100  a
 4. 101  c
```

So  i use this command!

```
sort -nt 't' -k 1 a.log
```

But the result is :

```
 1. 2    d
 2. 100  a
 3. 100  b
 4. 101  c
```

Thanks very much！

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You forgot to constrain the key fields. By default it uses until the end of the line.

```
sort -nst '\t' -k 1,1 0507.log
```

Comment: Thanks very much ! I test your command in my computer ,but "100 a" is still above "100 b"!  Dose the command  work  in your computer?

Comment: Is the delimiter actually a tab character?

Comment: Yes ! I check it again! it's a tab character

Comment: Ah. You also need to make it stable with `-s`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a peek at the [man page for sort](http://ss64.com/bash/sort.html)...

```
   `-n`, --numeric-sort

      compare according to string numerical value
```

So here is an example...

```
sort -n filename
```